# How to STOP wordpress trying to update database?

Tags: database

I have a current project which I have a lot of custom code to the core etc. I know it's not best practise but it is what it is... only problem is that wordpress is trying to force me to update my databse which cause me both a head & heart-ache to sort out. I'd like that not to happen again, I tried to remove everything from update.php but the warning still shows each time I try to login to the admin. Is there anyway to stop it? :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a [`DO_NOT_UPGRADE_GLOBAL_TABLES`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Do_not_upgrade_global_tables) constant that going by documentation protects tables that are global in multisites (since they can grow large because of that), but I don't see a clean way to prevent upgrade altogether.

I'd work on getting that core clean of hacks instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should never edit core. Your modifications should be done through [Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) or [Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).